# Replace integers in a list with a string Python

Tags: python, list

I am working on a coding assignment in Python and I am struggling to understand why my code is not working.

Write a function in Python called "BooHoo" which takes in an integer, n, and stores all integers from 1 to n in a list. However, if an integer in the list is divisible by 3, the list should instead contain "Boo". If the integer is divisible by 5 the list should instead contain "Hoo". If the integer is divisible by both 3 and 5, the list should instead contain "BooHoo".

```
def BooHoo(n):
'''
A function which returns a list of integers, and replaces integers divisible by 3 with "Boo" and integers
divisible by 5 with "Hoo" and integers divisible by 3 and 5 with "BooHoo"


Parameters
-------
n: an integer


Returns
--------

final_list: a Python list

'''

main_list = []
for x in range(n):
    main_list.append(x)


for idx, j in enumerate(main_list):
    if not (idx % 3) and not (idx % 5):
        main_list.pop(idx)
        main_list.insert(idx, 'BooHoo')
    elif not (idx % 3):
            main_list.pop(idx)
            main_list.insert(idx, 'Boo')
    elif not (idx % 5):
            main_list.pop(idx)
            main_list.insert(idx, 'Hoo')
    else:
        continue

final_list = [main_list]

return final_list
```

Comment: enumerate returns index, value. Try flipping the idx and j around.

Comment: There were some logical/implementational errors in your code. Check my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were some logical errors regarding the index and actual elements of the list. I have highlighted the modified/added lines by a comment `#`. Mainly, you needed to replace `idx` by `j` because `idx` was an index but `j` was an actual element. If you start by `range(n)`, it doesn't matter because the index is the same as `j`. But since you mentioned in your question, you want to store numbers from `1` up to `n`, you need to use `range(1, n+1)`

```
def BooHoo(n):
    main_list = []
    for x in range(1,n+1): # replaced range(n) to start from 1
        main_list.append(x)

    for idx, j in enumerate(main_list):
        if not (j % 3) and not (j % 5): # replaced idx by j
            main_list.pop(idx)
            main_list.insert(idx, 'BooHoo')
        elif not (j % 3): # replaced idx by j
                main_list.pop(idx)
                main_list.insert(idx, 'Boo')
        elif not (j % 5): # replaced idx by j
                main_list.pop(idx)
                main_list.insert(idx, 'Hoo')
        else:
            continue

    return main_list # Removed unnecessary second list

# Call the function
print (BooHoo(15))
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 'Boo', 4, 'Hoo', 'Boo', 7, 8, 'Boo', 'Hoo', 11, 'Boo', 13, 14, 'BooHoo']
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  How do I populate the output as separate items in the list, instead of a list of 16 items as one item in a list?  The assignment has an autograder that keeps saying my list only has a length of 1.

Comment: Do you mean `[[1], [2], ['Boo'], [4], ['Hoo]'...` and so on?

Comment: I think it needs to be [1,2,'Boo',4...so on, but I believe what you have there could work as well.

Comment: Check my edited answer above. That's exactly what I did by using `final_list = main_list` instead of `final_list = [main_list]`.

Comment: Oh, I missed that part.  Got it that time.  Perfect, thank you so much!  I have been banging my head on the wall for the last two hours on this!

Comment: `final_list = main_list` is truly unnecessary. All unreferenced local variables are removed when a function returns.

Comment: I feel this is overly complicated, why use `pop` and `insert` when we can just make a `for` loop and just the value of the item

Comment: @DYZ: I know, but I just wanted to help the OP by telling him/her problems in the code. There are much less verbose solutions but read what the OP stated **I am struggling to understand why my code is not working.**.

Comment: @vash_the_stampede: It's not my solution. I just answered what OP wanted. read my above comment. Clearly, he/she is a beginner and I thought of guiding him/her through the mistakes rather than providing one-liners

Comment: @Bazingaa wow you know what's funny I just left this exact comment to three other people asking why my answer didn't use more techniques and I even cited that was trying to help OP with their code not re writing a new one

Comment: I believe in first trying to find problem/error in OP's post if he/she have attempted a code and is not working, if there is no attempt I try to provide one. If the attempt is poor, I try to provide better alternatives if I can. This question belonged to the first category and so I just stuck to that

Comment: @Bazingaa but I do disagree with the beginner comment as to say that someone using a `for` loop , `enumerate` ,`pop` and `insert` can't use just a `for` loop

Comment: Well I am sorry for that word but I stand by my answering rules. At least someone has to explain him/her what's wrong with his/her implementation and how to make it work. I chose to be that guy especially when OP's question and aim is crystal clear ;) Moreover providing a shorter solution without explaining how it works is no good

Answer (score 0):

A better way to solve your problem is to construct the right list from the start (with a loop or list comprehension) than to modify a sequential list of numbers.

```
def BooHoo(n):
    return ['BooHoo' if not (i % 5 or i % 3) else 
               'Hoo' if not i % 5 else 
               'Boo' if not i % 3 else 
                   i for i in range(1,n+1)]
```

And, more for the sake of fun than usefulness, a dictionary-based solution:

```
def BooHoo(n):
    words = {(1,1): 'BooHoo', (1,0): 'Boo', (0,1): 'Hoo'}
    return [words.get((i % 3 == 0, i % 5 == 0), i) for i in range(1, n+1)]
```

Comment: You might want to replace `range(1,n)` by `range(1,n+1)` for reasons provided in the question

Answer (score 0):

Why go through all that trouble of appending and popping so much, thats not necessary

```
def BooHoo(n):

    for index, item in enumerate(list(range(1, (n+1))):
        if not item % 5 and not item % 3:
            lista[index] = "BooHoo"
        elif not item % 3:
            lista[index] = "Boo"
        elif not item % 5:
            lista[index] = "Hoo"
        else:
            pass

    return lista 

print(BooHoo(25))
```

**Output**

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 boohoo.py
> [1, 2, 'Boo', 4, 'Hoo', 'Boo', 7, 8, 'Boo', 'Hoo', 11, 'Boo', 13, 14, 'BooHoo', 16, 17, 'Boo', 19, 'Hoo', 'Boo', 22, 23, 'Boo', 'Hoo']
> ```

Comment: 1. `print` and `return` is not the same; `print` is almost always wrong . 2. There is no need for `list` in `list(range(1, (n+1)))`.

Comment: @DYZ for the loop I can just use `enumerate(range(n+1)`?

Comment: Correct. Both `list` and `range` are iterables.

Comment: @DYZ and where is `print` being compared to `return` in this ? Its not acceptable for a function to `print` and have no `return`?

Comment: Almost never. The purpose of a function (and of this function in particular) is to produce an object that could be used by the caller. If the caller decides to print it later, so be it. But if you print the value in the function, it cannot be used anymore.

Comment: @DYZ I agree I guess I was rushing, OP never mentioned storing it only printing, but that was me being lazy

Comment: The first line of the function docstring says, "A function which _returns_ a list of integers..."

Comment: @DYZ oh wow, I dropped the ball here, sorry will pick up the slack